# C++11 passing member function call through deduced type parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have a C++11 function:

```
template<class F, class... Args>
void g(F&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    /* ... */

    forward<F>(f)(forward<Args>(args)...);

    /* ... */
}
```

and I have a class `X`:

```
struct X
{
    void h();
}
```

Is there some way I can pass a call to `h` on a specific `X` instance `x` as parameters `f, args` through `g`?

```
X x = ...;

g(x.h);  // WRONG
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `std::mem_fn`:

```
X x = ...;

g(mem_fn(&X::h), x);
```

Comment: Though, I think the OP wants `x` to already be bound as first argument and thus for `args` to match the arguments of `h`. If not, then `std::mem_fn` is indeed far superior to `std::bind`.

Comment: Any arguments to h can be passed after x: `g(mem_fn(&X::h), x, arg1, arg2, arg3);`

Comment: Yeah, but still `args` doesn't exactly match the arguments of `h`, but if it's that what you want, you're fine. Wait, I think *ipc*'s solution doesn't even work for an `h` with arguments, so I think yours is the only correct solution.

Comment: The `args` parameter of `g` are the arguments forwarded to the `f` parameter of `g`, they are not necessarily the arguments of a member function in the cases when `g` is called with a member function.

Comment: That's what I'm saying and if this is no problem for you `std::mem_fn` is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
g(x.h); // WRONG
```

This fails because `x.h` isn't a plain function, it's a function with `this` bound to `&x`.

There are two possibilities to add the missing binding:

```
g([&](){x.h();}); // lambda
g(std::bind(&X::h, std::ref(x))); // std::bind
```

If you want to call `h` with a copy of `x`, then change the `[&]` to `[=]` in the lambda (and similary, remove the `std::ref`).

The lambda may be a little bit faster tough.

Comment: I'd change capture clause to `&x`.

Comment: I think, this won't work for `x::h` taking any additional arguments (at least not without cluttering the `std::bind` call with `std::placeholder`s yourself, not to speak of the lambda version).